# Can we get the image for (at least) the gmail contacts found in the user's contact list?

Tags: php, google-api, google-contacts-api, google-image-search

I am currently getting email and name, like this:

```
function tratar_gmail($accesstoken){
    $max_results = 3000;
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results='.$max_results.'&oauth_token='.$accesstoken;
    //echo $url;
    $xmlresponse =  curl_file_get_contents($url);
    if((strlen(stristr($xmlresponse,'Authorization required'))>0) && (strlen(stristr($xmlresponse,'Error '))>0))
    {
        echo "<h2>OOPS !! Something went wrong. Please try reloading the page.</h2>";
        exit();
    }
    $xml =  new SimpleXMLElement($xmlresponse);
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
    $result = $xml->xpath('//gd:email');
    $return;

    foreach ($result as $title) {

      $parts = explode('@', $title->attributes()->address);


      $pos = count($return);
      $return[$pos]['email'] = $title->attributes()->address;
      $return[$pos]['name'] = strip_tags($parts[0]);
    }
```

Where `$title` dumps:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {   ["@attributes"]=>   array(3) {     ["rel"]=>     string(38) "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other"     ["address"]=>     string(18) "xxxxxxx@wanadoo.es"     ["primary"]=>     string(4) "true"   } }
```

But it would be great to get some images, at least for the gmail contacts, is there a way?

something like:

```
$return[$pos]['email'] = $title->attributes()->address;
$return[$pos]['name'] = strip_tags($parts[0]);
if (preg_match('/^gmail.com/', $return[$pos]['emal']) {
     $return[$pos]['pic'] = magic_goes_here()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The photo link can be found in the contact entry:

```
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
    xmlns:gContact='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008'
    xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
    gd:etag='{contactEtag}'>
  <id>
    http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/base/{contactId}
  </id>
  ...
  <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo' type='image/*'
    href='https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/{userEmail}/{contactId}'
    gd:etag='{photoEtag}'/>
```

If there is no photo, the `link` element will not have the attribute `gd:etag`.

To retrieve the image for each contact, GET that URL:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/{userEmail}/{contactId}
```

[Full documentation for Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, any chance that you adapt my code to get the image in the `foreach` ?

Comment: Basically, I can't find any contactId in the response.. any thoughts? thanks!

Comment: What is the response you're getting? Can you create a pastebin with the info in it?

Comment: It outputs this `object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["rel"]=>
    string(38) "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other"
    ["address"]=>
    string(18) "xxxxxxx@wanadoo.es"
    ["primary"]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
}` for each `$title`, that helps?